# Word boundary regex with RegExp in javascript

Tags: javascript

> Owe no one anything to another

```
> str.replace(/\bno\b/g, 'yes');
'Owe yes one anything to another'

> str.replace(new RegExp('\bno\b','g'),'yes');
'Owe no one anything to another'
```

Why does using RegExp not work in this case? I need to use it so that I can

```
var regex = new RegExp('\b'+ **myterm** +'\b','g');  or
var regex = new RegExp('(^|\s)'+ **myterm** +'(?=\s|$)','g');
```

Comment: `"\b"` is the [backspace character (U+0008)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0008/index.htm) Where as you want backslash and a b (`"\\b"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your backslashes when using a RegExp string in this way:

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\\bno\\b', 'g'), 'yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `\b` had to be escaped, e.g.,

```
new Regexp('\\b' + **myterm** + '\\b');
```

Comment: Again? when was the first time it was escaped? `\b` isn't an escaped `b`.